# Joomla 2.5 mod_banners how to add additional templates?

Tags: joomla2.5

How can I add additional templates to mod_banners in j2.5?  From the module configuration you can choose the template - which is just default.php by default.

I've tried adding my modified template to the tmpl folder but it doesnt appear in the drop down in the module parameters - can anyone shed any light?  I want to use multiple templates so I have already modified tmpl/default.php

Comment: can you add the full file path and the file name of the new template?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.  mod_banners is a standard module in joomla.  My new template lives in root/modules/mod_banners/tmpl/my_template.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filename should be `mytemplate.php`. Joomla uses underscores to process templates and sub template files. The dropdown checks for files without an underscore and only shows those.

That form field uses the field type `modulelayout`. This core layout uses a regex to avoid names with underscores in them: `^[^_]*\.php$`.

No underscore and you will be good to go.